# Jquery - use e.preventDefault on form and add parameters

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use e.preventDefault and add some parameters on form submit?

Here is my code:

```
 $("#myform").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var currentTarget = e.target;


        // add here my post parameters 


    });
```

Comment: Not working... $("#myform").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var currentTarget = e.target;

$('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'shai').attr('value', '12345').appendTo('#myform');
        // add here my post parameters 


    });

Comment: If you wants to send form after your changes, you should remove `e.preventDefault()` and add `return true` as described in the answer above